# Separating key values from a string in Swift that looks like an object array

Tags: ios, swift

If I do this:

```
let retrievedJson = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
 print(retrievedJson)
```

I get this in the console:

```
[{"label":"20-05-16","value":"67p4i"},{"label":"20-05-17","value":"d17bz"}]
```

How do I take this string and make two separate arrays.

ex:

```
["20-05-16", "20-05-17"]

["67p4i", "d17bz"]
```

Is there also a method to convert a String looking like an array to an array?

Comment: Don't. Decode the JSON into a struct. Multiple arrays are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
    let keys = res.map { $0.label } // ["20-05-16", "20-05-17"]
    let values = res.map { $0.value } // ["67p4i", "d17bz"]
  }
  catch { 
    print(error)
  }
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let label, value: String
}
```